# ASP.NET MVC3 - Distributing EditorTemplate in library project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to distribute an EditorTemplate control ASCX along with a type in a library project and have it be used by MVC3 when the type is rendered with the `EditorFor()` method?

---

Where I work we have a lot of `DateTime`, `Gender` and a few more custom fields which have a specific but concsistent way of (HTML) input and a corresponding backing ViewModel type for them (i.e. DateTimeViewModel with separate month, day, year field etc.) and they are in a shared library project.

However we still have to copy the EditorTemplates for these types to each project which is not very DRY.

So is there a way to bundle such EditorTemplate along with the library project and make sure that it's used when the corresponding ViewModel is used without having to copy all EditorTemplate to every projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a custom VirtualPathProvider to achieve this but nothing out of the box. Here's a [blog post](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) you may take a look at.

Disclaimer: Custom VirtualPathProviders don't work with precompiled web applications. So if you intend to precompile your web application before shipping don't use virtual path providers.

Because of this limitation personally I use custom [NuGet packages](http://nuget.codeplex.com/documentation?title=Creating%20a%20Package) that allow the developers to pull all the necessary templates to their corresponding locations.

Comment: +1 for using custom NuGet packages, it's sounds very interesting. Could you please write a few lines about it, explaining how it works? Because at the moment we are using a custom solution with embedded resources, similar to portable areas, but I really don't like it. :)

Comment: @Kalman Speier, I create a custom NuGet package that would contain all the necessary templates I want to be shared and when someone installs this NuGet package it pulls and deploys the files in their respective locations. See the article I've linked to about how to create a custom NuGet package. It's really extremely easy. You could also deploy additional assemblies with your templates (for example they could contain view models used by the templates), perform web.config transformations, T4 templates, ... extremely powerful. They are also updatable, so it is very easy to publish a new version.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own VS Template, Export it and distribute it to all of your developers I think.

[Write Templates for VS2010](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/VSExtnsnsTemplates2010.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can register your own VirutalPathProvider implementation:

```
HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new YourViewProvider());
```

Then you will be able to get your files from basically anywhere (for example from embedded resource).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not currently possible. ASP.NET MVC editor templates should be defined in a partial view file. There is no way to define them in code only.